# Wanted: Development workstation window application restore program

Tags: eclipse

I can't believe someone hasn't done this... and maybe they have, but I am an occasional developer (read: bad coder) that seems to have to quickly pick up a number of projects I've worked on in the past.

I'm rather particular about window placement and every time I have to pick up one of these projects, I seem to spend a ton of unproductive time arranging my desktop to my needs.  This seems like a waste.

Is there something out there, preferably for Linux, that would make it possible to create a snapshot of my development environment's important programs with window positions and let me simply restore them all in one shot?  It'd be a bonus to be able to do some basic shell scripting to tail important log files, bring up test scripts, look at repos, etc...

Anyone?

Comment: For which programming language? For which IDE? Or aren't you using an IDE?

Comment: Mostly Java, but I do integrated end to end stuff (small environment) that may require a test app or two, as well as server side debugging.  I use mostly Eclipse when I use an IDE, but half of what I do is vi. I'd ideally like something where I can feed window executables and positions + some basic shell scripting.